# if $h$ and $g$ are continuous, why is $f = g \circ h$ also continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

We had an exercise in functional analysis, which states

> Show that $f = \sin (\frac1x)$ is continuous

Part of the solution for case $ x \neq 0$ was:

$$ \sin \text{ is continuous } \land \frac1x \text{ is continuous} \Longrightarrow f \text{ is continuous}$$

Why is that?

Furthermore, we had also examples which state $f + g$ is continuous if $f$ and $g$ are continuous.

What kind of literature do I need to get a better read on these properties?

Comment: What definition of continuity are you working with? With respect to some it is almost immediate.

Comment: These are basic properties about continuous functions; any book on real analysis should cover these, say baby Rudin

Comment: @Keen-ameteur in this very example we have been working with the continuity definition using sequences. But for this example he just concludes from $g$ and $h$ being continuous, such that $f = g \circ h$ must be continuous too. The usual operators of $+$ and $-$ seem obvious to me. But chaining functions does not feel intuitive about the continuity property

Comment: Both cases can be dealt with by double applications of $\epsilon - \delta$ approaches

Comment: Well, using sequences, it's really trivial to conclude that $f = g\circ h$ is continuous. Take sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $c$. If $h$ is continuous, then what can you tell about the sequence $h(x_n)$? Now, apply the same logic to the sequence $(h(x_n))$ and continuous function $g$. Actually, it's more involved to prove that sum of two functions is continuous then it is for composition of functions.

Answer (score 1):

When asked what introductory book on analysis can be studied by the self-learner, my go-to answer is Ken Binmore's superb "Mathematical Analysis". Has a considerably large number of examples, easily-digested proofs, relevant and educational problems, and full answers to everything.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding Analysis
Book by Stephen Abbott.

This is also a wonderful book of real analysis with beautiful explanation and some good set of exercises. And you will get a teste of metric space and topological space.
It is very useful book  for beginner . Hope it helps.